# Muenchian Grouping rounding issue

Tags: xml, xslt, precision, muenchian-grouping

I am using muenchian Grouping but this is rounding values.

For Ex: 50.00 --> 50
        56.90 --> 56.9

This is causing problem with the xml consumer. Below is my stylesheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"  xmlns:bus="http://ws.fwk.com/business-call"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java" exclude-result-prefixes="fn java">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:key name="taxgrp" match="bus:VoPaidTax" use="concat(generate-id(..),bus:TaxCode, bus:TaxRate)" />

<xsl:template match="bus:BsAddOrderPaymentRequestPayload/bus:Request/bus:TotalPaidAmount/bus:TaxList">
    <bus:TaxList>            
<xsl:for-each select="bus:VoPaidTax[generate-id()
             = generate-id(key('taxgrp', concat(generate-id(..),bus:TaxCode, bus:TaxRate))[1])]">
   <bus:VoPaidTax>
     <bus:TaxAmount>
       <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('taxgrp', 
                                 concat(generate-id(..),bus:TaxCode, bus:TaxRate))/bus:TaxAmount)"/>
     </bus:TaxAmount>
     <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::bus:TaxAmount)]"/>
  </bus:VoPaidTax>
</xsl:for-each>      
   </bus:TaxList>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is an input and output XML:

```
<bus:BsAddOrderPaymentRequestPayload xmlns:bus="http://ws.fwk.com/business-call">
<bus:Request>
<bus:TotalPaidAmount>
<bus:GrossAmount>244.16</bus:GrossAmount>
<bus:NetAmount>218.00</bus:NetAmount>
<bus:VatAmount>26.16</bus:VatAmount>
<bus:TaxList>
<bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:TaxAmount>4.45</bus:TaxAmount>
<bus:TaxCode>10</bus:TaxCode>
<bus:TaxRate>0.05</bus:TaxRate>
<bus:TaxType>GST</bus:TaxType>
</bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:TaxAmount>6.23</bus:TaxAmount>
<bus:TaxCode>12</bus:TaxCode>
<bus:TaxRate>0.07</bus:TaxRate>
<bus:TaxType>PST</bus:TaxType>
</bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:TaxAmount>6.45</bus:TaxAmount>
<bus:TaxCode>10</bus:TaxCode>
<bus:TaxRate>0.05</bus:TaxRate>
<bus:TaxType>GST</bus:TaxType>
</bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:TaxAmount>9.03</bus:TaxAmount>
<bus:TaxCode>12</bus:TaxCode>
<bus:TaxRate>0.07</bus:TaxRate>
<bus:TaxType>PST</bus:TaxType>
</bus:VoPaidTax>
</bus:TaxList>
</bus:TotalPaidAmount>
</bus:Request>
</bus:BsAddOrderPaymentRequestPayload>
```

The Output XMl:

```
<bus:BsAddOrderPaymentRequestPayload xmlns:bus="http://ws.fwk.com/business-call">
<bus:Request>
<bus:TotalPaidAmount>
<bus:GrossAmount>244.16</bus:GrossAmount>
<bus:NetAmount>218.00</bus:NetAmount>
<bus:VatAmount>26.16</bus:VatAmount>
<bus:TaxList>
<bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:TaxAmount>10.9</bus:TaxAmount>
<bus:TaxCode>10</bus:TaxCode>
<bus:TaxRate>0.05</bus:TaxRate>
<bus:TaxType>GST</bus:TaxType>
</bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:VoPaidTax>
<bus:TaxAmount>15.26</bus:TaxAmount>
<bus:TaxCode>12</bus:TaxCode>
<bus:TaxRate>0.07</bus:TaxRate>
<bus:TaxType>PST</bus:TaxType>
</bus:VoPaidTax>
</bus:TaxList>
</bus:TotalPaidAmount>
</bus:Request>
</bus:BsAddOrderPaymentRequestPayload>
```

When I apply a number formatter the grouping no longer works and gives weird results. 
Also grouping function is rounding values to .01 less.
Ex: 41.67 + 17.17 = 58.84

But is being rounded to 58.83.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Could you minimize the example to only what's necessary to reproduce the problem, please?

Comment: So using e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('taxgrp', 
                                 concat(generate-id(..),bus:TaxCode, bus:TaxRate))/bus:TaxAmount), '0.00')"/>` does not give you the result you want?

Comment: I was using a number format template, this worked nicely. Thanks a lot.